# DOM access through javascript - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am accessing a children of a DIV element on Facebook post which I am going to use on my chrome extension. I am trying to get the `innerText` of that element. I can get that text through `document.getElementsByClassName("_42nr")[1].children[1].innerText;` it will return the **Comment** word of the first post of the Facebook on your timeline. But when I put an if condition to detect if the second children of that the inner text of the second element of `"_42nr"` class is **Comment** or by applying `toLowercase()` method and make it **comment** then the condition return false.

**My Code**

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("_42nr")[1]; 
if(el.children[1].innerText.toLowerCase()=="comment"){
 alert("true");
} else{
 alert("false");
}
```

You can run these codes in your browser console in chrome, to see what it return, the first statement return the inner text of that children, which is **Comment** but why it return false when I put a condition.

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without seeing the source code you are attempting to manipulate. Perhaps the element you are trying to target has not been created in the DOM at the time that your script runs.

Comment: no I am running this script in the console when the page is fully loaded, after that I run it.

Comment: Facebook is pretty dynamic, and HTML is being generated and modified on the fly. Something to consider.

Comment: Yes but, when I laod the facebook page, then I write this code in the console, the first line return the true value I need, but the condition one return false, you can try it in the console

Comment: Ran this in another tab. It looks like there is an additional whitespace at the end of the string, which could explain why it is returning false.

Console output:
> el.children[1].innerText
"Comment
"

Comment: It looks like a new line character.

Comment: That put the closing string to the new line yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(el.children[1].innerText.toLowerCase()=="comment\n"){
    alert("true");
} else{
    alert("false");
}
```

Or you can alternatively strip the whitespace.

```
if(el.children[1].innerText.toLowerCase().trim()=="comment"){
    alert("true");
} else{
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!